# Is there any way to define an element in React that can be used throughout the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

For example I have the following component:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function App() {
  function handleOver() {
    const target = document.getElementById("target")
    target.style.background = "red"
  }

  function handleLeave() {
    const target = document.getElementById("target")
    target.style.background = "green"
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        id="btn"
        onMouseOver={handleOver}
        onMouseLeave={handleLeave}>
          Test
      </div>
      <div
        id="target">
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Instead of defining target twice, can I define it once and call it from each event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `useRef`, **but also check recommended approach in second code snippet**.

```
import React from 'react'

export default function App() {
  const target = useRef();

  function handleOver() {
    target.current.style.background = "red"
  }

  function handleLeave() {
    target.current.style.background = "green"
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        id="btn"
        onMouseOver={handleOver}
        onMouseLeave={handleLeave}>
          Test
      </div>
      <div
         ref={target}>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

---

**But probably it's better not to manipulate the DOM like that yourself**, instead define some `backgroundColor` state variable with `useState` and use style binding like `<div style={{backgrondColor: myColorInState}}></div>` or assign a custom CSS class with these colors:

```
export default function App() {
  const [targetColor, setTargetColor] = useState(null);

  function handleOver() {
    setTargetColor("red");
  }

  function handleLeave() {
    setTargetColor("green");
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        id="btn"
        onMouseOver={handleOver}
        onMouseLeave={handleLeave}>
          Test
      </div>
      <div style={{background: targetColor}}></div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Do you not also need to check if `target.current` is not undefined as well?

Comment: By the time you trigger ```mouseOver``` and ```mouseLeave``` the ref will be bound, so not null. The problem appears if you're using it on component initialization, because the component needs to render at least once in order to bind the element to the ref. But check the end of my answer too, I'd not recommend manipulating the DOM for a simple case like that one.